# Getting the newest version (not the cached version) of a text file on a server using java Streams to read

Tags: java

I have a url of a text file and I want to read it:

```
URL url = new URL("example.com/textfile.txt");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String inpuline = null;
while ((inpuline = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inpuline);
}
in.close();
```

The problem is when I change the Content of `textfile.txt`, my program does not realize the changes next time it runs.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your client isn't caching the old version of the file and using that instead of the new version?

Comment: You mean the java program?

Comment: Yes, or maybe your operating system, or anything standing between your Java program and the server you're reading the file from (I assume it's a server from the example URL you gave) that might be caching the file.

Comment: Does it mean I should do something in my java code to not doing cache?

Comment: Not necessarily; most servers have some sort of mechanism for making sure that a cached version of a file can be overwritten by a new version when it exists.

Comment: Try adding `?cachebust=4623446` to the URL.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann added to the URL. no effect.

Comment: Do you have a proxy server in between that may be giving you old copy of the file ? try adding a very random token to the URL that changes every time like : `?rand=<some random value>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you change the txt file, you should verify that your server realized the changes and return the last version of your file. To verify this use a browser. If you didn't get the last version of your file something is wrong with the server. If you need to press `Ctrl+F5` it means that the maybe some proxies or your browser cashed the old file.

After all trying the following workarounds may helps:

```
try {
   URL url = new URL("example.com/textfile.txt");
   Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());
   // read from your scanner
}
catch(IOException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace(); // for now, simply output it.
}
```

If you got the cached version of your file again, then try to use HttpURLConnection to download the file and write it to a temp file. Then read from that temp file and after that delete that temp file. Maybe downloading the file can force the server to get the newest version of that file. To avoid cached version of your file try this:

```
// Create a URLConnection object
URLConnection connection = myURL.openConnection();

// Disable caching
connection.setUseCaches(false);
```

Good Luck.